# tkinter canvas enclosed shapes changing fill on click based on tags

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tags, fill

So I have two shapes in tkinter python3.0, with one shape enclosed inside the other. I have given them both different tags. On click, I want to fill the shape selected, with the color being different depending on the item's tag.

Upon trying this, I found that if I filled the inner shape first, I could fill the outer shape fine. However, if I did the opposite and filled the outer shape first, I could not fill in the inner shape for some reason. I tried doing tag_lower() and tag_raise(), but they don't change anything.

Below is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root,width=200,height=200,bg="white")
canvas.grid()
firstRect = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,30,30, tag="in")
secondRect = canvas.create_rectangle(15,15,25,25, tag="out")


def onclick(event):
    item = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    tags = canvas.gettags(item)
    if tags[0] == "in":
        canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="red")
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="blue")

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', onclick)
```

I cannot fill the inner shape after the outer one has been filled. How would I go about this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Add a inital fill: `.create_rectangle(..., tag="out", fill='white')`

Comment: I'm dumb. That worked thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a inital fill: .create_rectangle(..., tag="out", fill='white') – stovfl
Thanks to stovfl for finding out the problem